# Populating a Stoplist in SQL Server using SSDT

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-data-tools

I'm using SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) to manage my database project but I don't seem to be able to populate a FULLTEXT STOPLIST.

```
CREATE FULLTEXT STOPLIST [MyStopList] FROM SYSTEM STOPLIST;
SQL70010: A FROM clause is not supported for CREATE FULLTEXT STOPLIST statement
```

I'm using the latest version of Visual Studio 2015 and SSDTs.

Is there any way round this?

Comment: This is strange.  The command has supported `FROM` since SQL Server 2008 (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280405(v=sql.100).aspx).  Must be some strange configuration in SSDT.

Comment: It works successfully when executed on SSMS

Comment: Not in SSDT, I'll look into it on another project and post the answer, it would probably be do-able using a post deployment script.

Comment: Don't expect SSDT work for all SQL Server features. Post deployment script can perform any task.

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the same issue. Trying this in a post deploy script results in the same error. The FROM keyword gets underlined in red even before building the dacpac.

Just found this link with MS response.
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3d89831e-43d8-4fe5-8ca5-d604a93789cb/sql70010-a-from-clause-is-not-supported-for-create-fulltext-stoplist-statement?forum=ssdt

"There is no support for the FROM clause.  Because the from clause references a stop list definition that is not in the project, SSDT has no way of understanding the stoplist without the referenced database. This is one example where the declarative model limits some of the supported TSQL syntax as if the elements in the database are not completely defined in the project or referenced projects, SSDT cannot model them correctly in the project system."